# Messages on new terminal after using nohup

Tags: bash, shell-script, nohup, async

I'm trying to [run a few commands asynchronously](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/289221/56041) on a login script (`.bash_profile`).

When I open a new terminal, I see messages like this. They also show up when I log onto a system over SSH.

```
Last login: Sat Jun 11 19:21:44 on ttys001
[1]-  Exit 127    nohup -c 'git fetch -p && git pull' < /dev/null >&/dev/null  (wd: ~/cryptopp)
(wd now: ~)
[2]+  Exit 127    nohup -c 'git fetch -p && git pull' < /dev/null >&/dev/null  (wd: ~/openssl)
(wd now: ~)
```

The login script performs the following:

```
if [ -d "$HOME/cryptopp" ]; then
    cd "$HOME/cryptopp"
    nohup -c 'git fetch -p && git pull' </dev/null &>/dev/null &
fi

if [ -d "$HOME/openssl" ]; then
    cd "$HOME/openssl"
    nohup -c 'git fetch -p && git pull' </dev/null &>/dev/null &
fi
```

The extra redirect gyrations are due to [nohup:ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24646320). The extra single quotes are due to [How to escape single-quotes within single-quoted strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1250079)

If it matters, I'm working on OS X, so its using Bash 3. But the scripts usually run on Linux, BSD and Solaris, and I'm seeing it on Debian 8, too.

I have a few question. First, what is the problem `nohup` is complaining about? Second, how do I fix the problem `nohup` is complaining about? Third, how do I suppress messages like this?

Answer (score 6):

The output isn't coming from `nohup`, it's coming from your shell (bash).

You backgrounded those processes using `&`, and so the shell is telling you when the commands exit. If you don't want the shell to do that, you can use `disown`. Also, by using `disown`, you no longer need `nohup`. For example:

```
if [ -d "$HOME/cryptopp" ]; then
    (
        cd "$HOME/cryptopp"
        git fetch -p && git pull
    ) </dev/null &>/dev/null &
    disown $!
fi
```

In the example, we spawn a subshell with the redirections, background it, and then disown it.

Comment: Or just `nohup ... &>/dev/null`

Comment: @heemayl `nohup` doesn't run things in the background, and I assume the OP wants to background them because the commands can take a while.

Comment: Thats right. I was meaning to say like `nohup ... & &>/dev/null` which is of course not as straight forward as `disown` but as OP was at it so...

Comment: @Patrick - If you have something more efficient or easier to read, then please suggest it. I'm a C/C++/Objective C guy, and I glue these scripts together based on the subtask at hand. I'm happy to take suggestions and advice because its not my area of expertise. Plus, the "how do I..." questions are often too broad and don't show any effort by OP (and that's something I want to avoid).